# How do I concatenate each element of different lists together?

Tags: python

```
print(sgrades_flat)   
['Barrett', 'Edan', '70', '45', '59', 'Bradshaw', 'Reagan', '96', '97', '88', 'Charlton', 'Caius', '73', '94', '80', 'Mayo', 'Tyrese', '88', '61', '36', 'Stern', 'Brenda', '90', '86', '45']

print(s_grades)   
['F', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'C']
```

I want to combine sgrades_flat and s_grades to look like ...

```
['Barrett', 'Edan', '70', '45', '59', 'F',   
'Bradshaw', 'Reagan', '96', '97', '88', 'A'  
'Charlton', 'Caius', '73', '94', '80', 'B'   
'Mayo', 'Tyrese', '88', '61', '36', 'D'   
'Stern', 'Brenda', '90', '86', '45', 'C']
```

My current strategy is to use this code:

```
z=[]    
for i, x in zip(sgrades_flat[::5], s_grades):
  z.append(i+x)
print(z)
```

but that output is:

```
['BarrettF', 'BradshawA', 'CharltonB', 'MayoD', 'SternC']
```

Comment: The data structure should be fixed. Instead of having one long list, this should be a list of five lists `[[list1], [list2], etc]`

Comment: @MatBailie ok I've learned now how to create that grouped nested list, would the next step be to then iterate over that nested structure appending s_grades at the end of each element in the nest? and what does that look like..

Comment: Assuming `sgrades_flat` is now a list of lists; `z = [[*grades, s_grades[i]] for i, grades in enumerate(sgrades_flat)]`

Comment: Or, `z = [[*grades, new_grade] for grades, new_grade in zip(sgrades_flat, s_grades)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would combine the list by iterating manually on them:

```
sgrades_flat=['Barrett', 'Edan', '70', '45', '59', 'Bradshaw', 'Reagan', '96', '97', '88', 'Charlton', 'Caius', '73', '94', '80', 'Mayo', 'Tyrese', '88', '61', '36', 'Stern', 'Brenda', '90', '86', '45']

s_grades=['F', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'C']

it1 = iter(sgrades_flat)
it2 = iter(s_grades)

result = []
try:
    while True:
        for _ in range(5):
            result.append(next(it1))
        result.append(next(it2))

except StopIteration:
    pass

print(result)
```

prints

```
['Barrett', 'Edan', '70', '45', '59', 'F', 
 'Bradshaw', 'Reagan', '96', '97', '88', 'A',
 'Charlton', 'Caius', '73', '94', '80', 'B',
 'Mayo', 'Tyrese', '88', '61', '36', 'D', 
 'Stern', 'Brenda', '90', '86', '45', 'C']
```

(this still looks like a bad idea as a flat list is sub-optimal for such a data structure)

Note that a one-liner without any manual iteration also does the same:

```
import itertools
grouped_sgrades = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
       sgrades_flat[i:i+5]+[s_grades[i//5]] 
       for i in range(0,len(sgrades_flat),5)))
```

however, why flatten the lists?

```
grouped_sgrades = [sgrades_flat[i:i+5]+[s_grades[i//5]] for i in range(0,len(sgrades_flat),5)]
```

result is a nice list of lists, which is approaching some structured data:

```
[['Barrett', 'Edan', '70', '45', '59', 'F'],
 ['Bradshaw', 'Reagan', '96', '97', '88', 'A'],
 ['Charlton', 'Caius', '73', '94', '80', 'B'],
 ['Mayo', 'Tyrese', '88', '61', '36', 'D'],
 ['Stern', 'Brenda', '90', '86', '45', 'C']]
```

Comment: `[sgrades_flat[i*5:i*5+5]+[grade] for i, grade in enumerate(s_grades)]`?

Comment: Or expand the slice out into a list with the letter grade.  `[[*sgrades_flat[i*5:i*5+5], grade] for i, grade in enumerate(s_grades)]`

Comment: yes, that would work too

Comment: so if I had the non-flat version "sgrades=[['Barrett', 'Edan', '70', '45', '59'], ['Bradshaw', 'Reagan', '96', '97', '88'], ['Charlton', 'Caius', '73', '94', '80'], ['Mayo', 'Tyrese', '88', '61', '36'], ['Stern', 'Brenda', '90', '86', '45']]"
I would just iter(sgrades) and append s_grades? would that append to each list as an iterable?

Comment: Not sure of what you're asking, but creating `it = iter(sgrades)` allows to get successive values of `sgrades` by using `next(it)` is a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

You could use enumerate and then slice sgrades_flat accordingly:

```py
sgrades_flat = [
    'Barrett', 'Edan', '70', '45', '59',
    'Bradshaw', 'Reagan', '96', '97', '88',
    'Charlton', 'Caius', '73', '94', '80',
    'Mayo', 'Tyrese', '88', '61', '36',
    'Stern', 'Brenda', '90', '86', '45']

s_grades = ['F', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'C']

z = []
for i, x in enumerate(s_grades):
    z += sgrades_flat[5*i:5*(i+1)] + [x]

print(z)
```

Answer (score 1):

We need to iterate over both `s_grades` and `sgrades_flat` which we need to do 5 elements at a time. We can use a list comprehension with `range` based on 1/5th of the length of `sgrades_flat`. We can then use a second level of iteration in a list comprehension to bind `j` to that `i * 5` index.

```
[
 [*sgrades_flat[j:j+5], s_grades[i]] 
 for i in range(len(sgrades_flat) // 5)
 for j in (i * 5,)
]
# [['Barrett',  'Edan',   '70', '45', '59', 'F'], 
#  ['Bradshaw', 'Reagan', '96', '97', '88', 'A'], 
#  ['Charlton', 'Caius',  '73', '94', '80', 'B'], 
#  ['Mayo',     'Tyrese', '88', '61', '36', 'D'], 
#  ['Stern',    'Brenda', '90', '86', '45', 'C']]
```

Alternatively, iterating over `s_grades` with `enumerate`:

```
[
 [*sgrades_flat[j:j+5], g] 
 for i, g in enumerate(s_grades)
 for j in (i * 5,)
]

# [['Barrett',  'Edan',   '70', '45', '59', 'F'], 
#  ['Bradshaw', 'Reagan', '96', '97', '88', 'A'], 
#  ['Charlton', 'Caius',  '73', '94', '80', 'B'], 
#  ['Mayo',     'Tyrese', '88', '61', '36', 'D'], 
#  ['Stern',    'Brenda', '90', '86', '45', 'C']]
```